# Upgrade dailyLimitExceededUnreg

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have a wordpress pluging to booking class on my gym. This wordpress plugin works with Google calendar API and since yesterday I get the same error.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

Would be possible upgrade this limit? I don't care if I have to paid but need some solution. I have more or less 100 users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to authenticate yourself when using the Google Calendar API, which will allow you considerably larger quotas, you must include an API key in your request's URL. That can be done by simply appending the following [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) to it: `key=API_key`

Where `API_key` is the key obtained for that project.

In order to obtain an API key you can follow the steps below:

1. Go to [the API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).
2. From the projects list, select a project or create a new one.
3. If the APIs & services page isn't already open, open the left side menu and select **APIs & services**.
4. On the left, choose **Credentials**.
5. Click Create credentials and then select **API key**.

### Reference

- [Setting up API keys](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158862?hl=en)